# How can I only see one image at a time in the slider?

Tags: html, css

I created a slider with 4 images. When I opened it in the browser it is all clustered together instead of just one at a time. I also realize even thou the width and height should be the same a few images seem bigger. I'm not sure want I did wrong. This is what I have:

```css
#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 300%;
  height: 45%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: 10s slider infinite;
}

#slider figure img {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" width="50%" height="50%">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" width="50%" height="50%">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" width="50%" height="50%">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" width="50%" height="50%">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of the image to fit the screen so only one image shows at a time.
I realize it worked after adjusting that.

```
#slider figure{
    position:relative;
    width: 500%;
    height: 45%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: 10s slider infinite;
}
```